# Why is WritePrivateProfileString returning 0?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, dllimport, ini

In my C# application, I wish to update the values in an INI file.
I used the interop services and wish to use the function `WritePrivateProfileString`.
So I imported the DLL like this:

```
[DllImport("KERNEL32.DLL", EntryPoint = "WritePrivateProfileStringW",
           SetLastError = true,
           CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true,
           CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
private static extern int WritePrivateProfileString(
            string lpAppName,
            string lpKeyName,
            string lpString,
            string lpFilename);`
```

And used it in my function like this:

```
int result = WritePrivateProfileString(category, key, value, iniFile);
```

But the result is 0 and the INI file is not updated.
How can I check the error?

Comment: Any reason why you use interop instead of System.IO ?

Comment: **One possible problem is permissions.** It may not be the answer *here*, but it's going to be an issue once you deploy. If you're attempting to write to an INI file in the application directory (`C:\Program Files`) as a standard user, Windows Vista/7 are not going to let you. That's why INI files are no longer the typically recommended way of saving user configuration/data.

Comment: Yeah I think it is the permissions. But even though I give the read/write and modify permissions to the folder, The result is 0.

Comment: How are you trying to give it read/write permissions? No one but an Administrator can read or write to the Program Files folder. And if your application is not *running* as Administrator, it won't be able to do it either, regardless of how you're logged in. Like I said, riddled with problems.

Comment: @Cody I am not writing to program files. The ini files are used because they are used by an intermediate dll and we have no choice but to go ahead with them. When I meant giving rights, i meant to the folder containing the files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call the .NET equivalents to Win32 API functions `GetLastError` and `FormatMessage`, and the system will tell you why it's not letting you do this.

Cody is probably right in guessing that it is related to UAC, but without knowledge of where you are trying to write this file, we can only guess.

**Update**

As has been explained to me in the comments, [`Marshal.GetLastWin32Error`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getlastwin32error.aspx) is the .NET way to get hold of the error code rather than calling `GetLastError` directly. Calling `GetLastError` directly will return the error code of the latest call to the Win32 API, which is likely to have been from a .NET runtime call to Win32 rather than your P/Invoke.

Comment: Pretty much accurate to guess 90% of problems of this nature are related to UAC. Before Stack Overflow, I thought UAC was a giant pain in the rear. Now, I'm thankful it's catching buggy problems before they get deployed on unsuspecting users. (Sidenote: You shouldn't call `GetLastError` directly from managed .NET code. `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error` is the ticket there.)

Comment: @Cody, fair enough, I don't really know .net, but you call the .net wrappers to those 2 methods. UAC is great though, I've always loved it. Well, after it took a week to get used to it and work it out!!

Comment: Between the time his code calls WritePrivateProfileString and GetLastError, the .NET runtime has likely called many more Win32 APIs - reseting the result of GetLastError for each call.  Hence, the value returned from GetLastError in a C# app can't be trusted.  That's just a guess - I knew that was true with VB many years ago.

Comment: @selbie That makes perfect sense. Presumably it's alright to call `FormatMessage` because that does not depend on state and receives the error code as a parmaeter.

Comment: @selbie [The MSDN page for Marshal.GetLastWin32Error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getlastwin32error.aspx) explicitly mentions that is why you may never call GetLastError directly but must use Marshal.GetLastWin32Error.

Answer (score 6):

The [Marshal.GetLastWin32Error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getlastwin32error.aspx) should help you.

Comment: After using Marshal.GetLastWin32Error the error code i get is 5. Which Indicates Acess Denied .. HMm I 'll try setting the permissions again Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Application data/parameter files should be saved to an application-specific folder within the system's LocalApplicationData special folder either for a specific user or for all users.

Your app will have proper permissions to write here. This can be a per-user special folder, so ini settings will be unique for each user.

You can retrieve the LocalApplicationData special folder using:

```
string path = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
```

Create a folder here for your application, and store your ini file(s) within it.

On the file system the LocalApplicationData special folder by default maps to:

(XP/2k3) C:\Documents and Settings\user_account\Local Settings\Application Data\

(Vista/2k8/7/8) C:\Users\user_account\AppData\Local\

Comments regarding *"ini files are not recommended"* are imho wrong.

If you don't like the ini file format and API for PrivateProfile strings, then use XML files for your app settings, or roll your own settings data file format.

Just keep your application data in files in the LAD special folder and not in the registry.

I recommend that all third-party software apps use the LAD folder for per user initialization data/parameters and not the Registry. The system registry tends to become filled with left over junk as many software applications do not clean up and remove their registry keys when they perform upgrades or uninstalls.